# How do you build a square from this figure?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, tiling

[image]

If you can use only this figure, what is the LEAST number of such figures that you can use to build a square ?
You can use any isometry to build a square and it must be full from the inside.

Comment: Isn't 1 enough ? there already a lot of squares here

Comment: Are you joking, sorry ?

Comment: @stity You have to build a square shape using as many shapes as you want that are like the one above (and I suppose you can rotate or reverse them).

Comment: ok I thought that I had to use it as some kind of rule :)

Comment: Try 4, if cannot find solution try 9 then 16 and so on. Other options are not relevant.

Comment: @z100 how so ?.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That is indeed the right answer if you want you can post it as an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Since there are nine small squares here (and 9 is a square number), to build a square you must multiply by a square number, that is, use a square number of shapes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is 4. They form a svastika-like pattern (take one of your shape, and make it rotate around the smallest side, by 90°, and repeat this.

[image]

Comment: Proof? Why not 3 or 2?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Side length has to be at least 5, meaning at least 25 tiles, which rules out 2. 3 is ruled out since 27 is not a square.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro See my comment to the question.

Comment: Also the square must be a multiple of 9.  36 is the smallest square multiple of 9 >= 25.

Answer (score 1):

One can also generalize this; if you kept going with the spiral pattern (placing a strip of 7 squares at the end of the previous strip) for all 4 pieces, you would have a square of 8 units.

It's not hard to show inductively that you could continue this without bound to make arbitrarily large squares with even side length.